# Why @Responsebody is required in a DELETE request and not in POST, PUT or GET?

Tags: rest, http, spring-mvc

I have 3 different methods in a Controller class attending requests from POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path1", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ReturnDataType insertRequestDataType(@RequestBody RequestDataType requestData) throws ServiceException {
    //Some code here to call service class and do something with requestData
    return new ReturnDataType();
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/path2", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ReturnDataType updateRequestDataType(@RequestBody RequestDataType requestData) throws ServiceException {
    //Some code here to call service class and do something with requestData
    return new ReturnDataType();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "path3/{arg1}/path4/{arg2}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody ReturnDataType deleteRequestDataType(@PathVariable String arg1, 
                       @PathVariable String arg2) throws ServiceException {
            //Some code here to call service class and do something with arg1 and arg2
            return new ReturnDataType();
}
```

First two methods are working perfectly fine without `@ResponseBody` annotation in the return types, but last one is not. If I remove the annotation from the third method, I'll get the following error:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "cause": "Request method 'DELETE' not supported",
  "message": "Request Error"
}
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So if you remove `@ResponseBody`, your `deleteRequestDataType` method was executed actually, but this error happened when method returned?

Comment: Spring MVC itself doesn't create that response. What other frameworks do you use?

Comment: Only Spring, but I'm using Postman for Chrome to test these requests calls, and http response is showing that in Postman.

Comment: @Reno no, actually method is not executed, I set a breakpoint to make sure the method is hit but the request never makes it to the method itself. The moment I add `@RequestBody`, `deleteRequestDataType` method is executed.